# Craft subdomains

Tags: craft3

I am looking at creating an events site, and am thinking about using subdomains for each event. They will all be micro-sites listing exhibitors, timetables etc. I would like the domain structure to be something like:

`eventone.amazingevents.com`
`eventtwo.amazingevents.com`

and so on. The editor would need to be able to create these through Craft, and then add pages within them. Is this possible within Craft, and if so is there any best practice for this? The micro-site frameworks would be very similar, just with different content.

Thanks for any insight

Mike

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible and fairly easy to setup.

I would suggest checking out this page:
https://mijingo.com/lessons/craft-3-multi-site/

Here is how you can accomplish this:

1. Create your subdomains and point their document roots to the same location.
2. In Craft->Settings->Sites, add each subdomain as a site
3. Add sections and turn them on for each site.

Use the toggle that appears at the top in the dashboard to change sites.